# If I set up DHCP and static IP simultaneously, Google nameserver becomes unreachable

Tags: networking

[image]

Currently I have two network interfaces, ens160(DHCP) and ens192(static).

However, if these two NICs alive together, `ping 8.8.8.8` is blocked so I can't update any packages. If I shut down ens192, Google DNS becomes reachable.

What is the problem? How can I set up two interfaces without blocking access to nameserver 8.8.8.8?

This is my gateway information.
[image]

Comment: What is your gateway? Please add the output of route -n

Comment: @matteonunziati I added the result of `route -n`.

Comment: Ok try disabling ens160 and run only on the static ip . Also traceroute 8.8.8.8 with ens192. This is a routing issue. The static ip is killing your routing.